# Socket não recebe nem envia mensagem para o servidor

Tags: java, servidor, socket, multithreading

Estou implementando um servidor multi thread Java que recebe mensagens dos clientes e faz um broadcast delas para os demais. Porém estou tendo problemas. O servidor só recebe as mensagens enviadas para os usuários quando os sockets dos usuários são fechados.

A aplicação está dividida em dois módulos: `client` para os códigos do cliente e `server` para os códigos do servidor.

[Aqui](https://github.com/Alpha-Phoenix/Unscramble-Me-2.0/tree/test) está o código do meu projeto no GitHub para quem se sentir mais à vontade de vê-los lá. **Por favor faça o checkout no branch `test` e não no `master`**

Os códigos estão todos muito bem comentados e simples de entender.

Como já fiz essa pergunta no stack overflow inglês, vou apenas colocar um link para ela [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49835290/socket-not-receiving-or-sending-message-from-to-server). Os códigos estão todos lá.

Answer (score 0):

Chame `PrintWriter.flush()` após cada `write()` enviando mensagem para fazer os dados serem efetivamente transmitidos.

Answer (score 0):

Toda vez que você escrever algo através de um objeto PrintWriter é super recomendado que você chame o método flush() para "desengasgar" a saída. Então como o amigo já disse: Após o `socketWriter.write(line)` escreva `socketWriter.flush()`.